# User foreign key in same model getting updated together in sql database

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

```
models.py  
  class test(models.Model):
           data = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True)
           recordname = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True)
           recordname2 = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True)
           a_names = models.ForeignKey(User,  related_name='a_names', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
            b_names = models.ForeignKey(User,  related_name='b_names', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)

forms.py
    class Test1ModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Test1
            fields = ('id', 'a_names','data', 'recordname')

    class Test2ModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
            class Meta:
                model = Test1
                fields = ('id', 'b_names','data', 'recordname2')

views.py 
def Testing(request, pk):
    form = Test1ModelForm(instance=pk)
    if form.is_valid():
       form.save()

def Testing1(request, pk):
    form = Test2ModelForm(instance=pk)
    if form.is_valid():
       form.save()
```

the problem is, when the data is getting updated in the database, both a_names and b_names are getting updated.
Step 1: User "a_names" is updating "recordname"
Step 2: User "b_names" is updating "recordname1"

Comment: one of the reasons could be, both a_names and b_names are pointing to the same `user instance` in the model. 
Please add an example in your question for more explanation.

Comment: I have a single record in table. Then there is a workflow. Once user "a_names" updates it, then only user "b_names" can update the record

Comment: It would be great if you can add those snippets of code to your question because it's not very clear.

Comment: I have added few more items in the model and forms, hope this can help

Comment: okay, what is `pk` here? , the `instance` should be assigned with an instance else you should be creating a new Article. Since the code is working for you, I suppose the instance you passing as `pk` already has values for both a_names and b_names. For testing purposes, pass a different user for a_names under form `Testing` and see if both are getting updated with the same value or if it's retaining the old ones, please.

Comment: PK is the id passed from form.

Comment: a_names and b_names are logged in users.

Comment: see according to this doc `https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/`, `instance` field should always have an instance object assigned and not a `pk` which is an integer, so in the first place, the form saving itself isn't shouldn't work.  But unless you can recreate the issue with an example and share it with us, we wouldn't be able to help. Share what was the previous values of the instances and after filling the form, what were the values of the instances. That will really help.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no difference between the two line - except the field name - those two fields always be the same.

```
models.py  
  class test(models.Model):
           a_names = models.ForeignKey(User,  related_name='a_names', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
           b_names = models.ForeignKey(User,  related_name='b_names', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
```

what do you want to achieve?

Comment: But I am not passing b_names in form, shouldnt this be empty in the table, if m not sending the value